# App crashes on launch after adding Firebase Authentication dependency

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm integrating firebase authentication into my android project with firebase assistant. After integrating firebase auth, it adds a dependency `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'`  . when I use this dependency app crashes on launch.

and this is the log cat error

```
2021-07-13 14:03:04.319 20371-20371/? E/.store.admi: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-07-13 14:03:04.719 20371-20371/app.store.admin W/.ugpapers.admi: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory;->metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; (blacklist, linking, denied)
2021-07-13 14:03:04.719 20371-20371/app.store.admin D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-07-13 14:03:04.720 20371-20371/app.store.admin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.ugpapers.admin, PID: 20371
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discoverLazy(ComponentDiscovery.java:112)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(FirebaseApp.java:418)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:299)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2102)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2076)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7430)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6934)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6851)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:242)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
2021-07-13 14:03:04.739 20371-20371/app.store.admin I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20371 SIG: 9
```

after referring to my old projects I used the old dependency `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.4'` and now it's working fine.

Why is the latest dependency not working for me? I'm testing my app on `android 10` device.
Also if I add the latest firestore dependency, the app crash on launch.

what's going wrong here?